# fetch data which come from firebse

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I just wanted to fetch that data which coming from this https://food-ordring-af14d-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/order the data is in the form of JSON and it looks like that

> 

```
{
  "-MzJLd0sSssh9tbJbjUS" : {
    "orderDetails" : [ {
      "amount" : 4,
      "id" : "m1",
      "name" : "Shushi",
      "price" : 22.99
    }, {
      "amount" : 3,
      "id" : "m2",
      "name" : "Schnitzel",
      "price" : 16.5
    } ],
    "user" : {
      "address" : "A-132 shiv vihar,rishal garden,Nangloi",
      "city" : "New delhi",
      "name" : "Bhupender Sharma",
      "postal" : "110041"
    }
  },
  "-MzJOf_52xhRQi3izTRV" : {
    "orderDetails" : [ {
      "amount" : 2,
      "id" : "m3",
      "name" : "Barbecue Burger",
      "price" : 12.99
    }, {
      "amount" : 2,
      "id" : "m4",
      "name" : "Green Bowl",
      "price" : 18.99
    } ],
    "user" : {
      "address" : "Nangloi",
      "city" : "New delhi",
      "name" : "ANkit",
      "postal" : "445575"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! What is your question, where are you stuck exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. here some example

```js
const fetchdata = async()=>{
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  const jdata = await response.json()
  console.log(jdata)
}

fetchdata()
```